# Macbook7.1 (Macbook mid-2010 ) White unibody bottom rubber falling off

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

The bottom cover on my Macbook7.1 (mid-2010) White Unibody is beginning to fall of. I tried using some glue that a guy from a repair shop I could use for rubber-on-aluminium. I tried it and all I got is an awful smell of the glue which sticked right off, and couldn't hold it for long.I can clean the glue off, and I can try a second time to stick it back. Anyone any suggestions on a glue? Or a cheap new bottom rubber cover for my Macbook? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

There is a [replacement program](https://www.apple.com/support/macbook-bottomcase/) for this issue that still seems to be active. My wife's Macbook was also affected, and Apple mailed us out a free replacement replacement kit (comprising replacement part, screws and screwdriver) a couple of years ago.